# Search random char text file for words

Tags: string, search, random, char, words

this is my first question here so please be nice :)

I have a 60MB text file of random characters, with no whitespaces, tabs, newlines, or any determinable patterns. I think there is a word in this text file I need, although I'm not sure how to search it. I was thinking you could use a dictionary and scan the file, although that might take awhile and I don't know how to actually do that since there are no spaces or anything to separate words from characters.

Any help or ideas are appreciated.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005246/efficient-search-for-words-in-string) thread which might help, but I'm really not sure as the answer was unclear to me and I think our problems are slightly different.

Also any basic code/psuedocode helps, don't worry about the language :)

Comment: You just want to see if any English words are in the text file? Or are you looking to find an instance of a certain word?

I think strpos() would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to find all English words in the text file. And thanks I'll look that up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure?  Build a trie of your dictionary values, then start scanning through your text file character by character.  You'll need to maintain a set of candidate word fragments and what node they've led you to (so far) in the trie.  For each character read, iterate through the candidate list, and if the new character leads to a valid node in the trie the candidate remains in the list and the node info gets updated.  Otherwise remove it from the list.  If it's a word node, add the word to your solution set of found words.  If it's a leaf node remove it from the candidate set, otherwise retain it because some words are substrings of other words -- for example, "under" is itself a word, but in a trie could also lead you to "underwater", "underground", or "underdog" to name a few.